# Перенос приложений на другой аккаунт

Tags: android, перенос

Мне дали доступ по почте к аккаунту-разработчика, я опубликовал на этом аккаунте свои приложения. Спустя какое-то время купил свой личный аккаунт и захотел перенести свои приложения в него. Почитал туториалы гугла, вроде все легко и просто, но в моем случае возникла проблема. 
Чтобы перенести приложение из одного аккаунта-разработчика в другой, нужен код транзакции платежа (генерируется после покупки аккаунта). Код транзакции своего аккаунта я могу получить, а код другого, к которому у меня доступ по почте – нет, так как недостаточно прав. И связи нет с хозяином аккаунта. Хотел узнать, можно ли как-то перенести приложения без кода транзакции? Писал в гугл-плей поддержку, переадресовали меня на play developers, и сказали, что на русском языке пока поддержка не осуществляется.

Comment: чисто как вариант - выгрузить из одного акк все данные, и загрузить в другой, при условии что ничего больше не получится

Comment: все права принадлежат владельцу, только через него, надо было раньше думать

Comment: @Style-7 Это площадка, куда обращаются с конкретными проблемами, чтобы получить конкретное решение. А колхозные ответы, типа "раньше надо было думать", здесь не принято давать.

Comment: @McDaggen вы даже ответ от комментария отличить не можете

Comment: @McDaggen а что здесь не принято, так пытаться хамить людям которые тратят время на вас